# why kinect noise can be categorized into lateral and axial noise?

Tags: kinect, noise, noise-reduction

Recently I read some paper talk about modeling Kinect sensor noise model, the author said they category the noise into two categories: axial noise and lateral noise. [Modeling Kinect Sensor Noise for Improved 3D Reconstruction and Tracking](https://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/a8a6/18363b8dee8037df9133668ec8dcd532ee4e.pdf).Here is a 
[image from paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz2zj.png) shows how their breif idea.

I am new to this domain and don't know anything about this, I hope someone could give a clear explanation it to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Axial Noise in Kinect**: Noise in the depth measurement, 'along the axis of measurement (z-axis)' that is proportional to the depth measured (i.e. More noise at farther distances).

Axial noise is measured from the difference between depth measured and a fitted plane.

**Lateral Noise**: Noise in the depth measurement, at a direction perpendicular z-axis, due to the angle of the surface wrt the Kinect measurement plane.

Lateral noise is measured at vertical edges of a surface at an angle to the kinect.

"The spread of lateral noise distributions (obtained in pixels) does not vary significantly with z-distance. In contrast, the spread of axial noise distributions (obtained in meters) clearly increases with z-distance." (Page 3 of the paper)

The figure shows that the noise is gaussian in nature, and has a standard deviation, which they used to refine the depth measurement for Kinect fusion.